# How can I display a message to the user at a certain time Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I was wondering how I could display a simple message to the user at the top of their screen at a certain time in Django. I haven't been able to find anything online about this, so I was wondering how I would go about doing this.

Would I need to do something with DateTime? What view/model would I include the code in?

Thanks for any help you can give :)

Comment: You don't need django to do this. That's simple javascript `alert` using datetime.

Comment: Explore celery to send realtime alerts/notifications to users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I still don't have enough reputation to comment:

So just tell me when you 'read' this answer and I will delete it.
If you want you might copy / paste the interesting parts into a comment.

I think the exact use case is very important for giving the right answer.It all depends what exactly you mean with 'certain time'.

1. Notification time is known upfront (javascript alert)
2. Asking the Django server periodically can determine when to send the message (polling long / polling)
3. The Django server needs to perform some background task and the message should be sent at the end of this task

If you know already upfront (at the time the user opens the page) when this notification should happen, then Kostas Charitidis is right.
The page can just use javascript to program a timer and it will be the web browser who can at the given time make a request to Django to fetch an display the message.

To 'push' anything from a web server to a web browser at a given time one requires something like continous polling, long polling, web-sockets.

If the notification time is not known upfront, then 
a polling approach would for example use a piece of javascript, that periodically (every few seconds / minutes / depending on your use case) queries the Django server whether a message should be fetched.

Long polling is an approach where the web browser performs a get request to the server and the server stalls the answer until the message should be sent. (if the requests times out a new polling request will be initiated)
However to use long polling (efficiently) you'd need some special plugins on the server side to make this efficient / resource friendly.

If your web site does not need to be accessed from behind some old corporate (or paranoid) firewalls, then you might consider using web sockets (but there are still some public services / big companies who do block web sockets)

django-channels ( https://pypi.org/project/channels/ ) can help you with web socket notifications and some background tasks

celery ( https://pypi.org/project/celery/ ) can help you with running periodic / defered / tasks, but does not contain the means to send the message to your browser.
Celery is one of the most recommended solutions, but is (in my opinion) rather painful to set up.

Depending on the project something lighter (like for example django-background-tasks https://pypi.org/project/django-background-tasks/ ) might do the job

You might look at the django message frame work ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/) . But very probably it is not the right answer in your context.

Comment: Have an upvote to help you get the reputation to comment as it is a good comment.

Comment: Thanks Matthew.

As I'm still not really used to SO ettiquete:
Shall I better leave this as an answer or copy paste the text into a comment and delete this answer?

Comment: If you delete it, you lose the upvotes which allow you to comment. :)  Besides, I think it works as an answer given the generality of the question. You have outlined the various options and why one might use them very well.

Comment: I think this sums it up pretty well thanks, I'll look into it

Comment: @gelonida hey, you had what you thought was a comment and instead got your first best answer and beat out the rest of us. Congrats.

Comment: Glad my answer is helpful.
@jeremy_lord Don't hesitate to post a question as soon as you identified / fixed your exact use case

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any model to do this,

**Option 1**

Use ajax (Use when you want to refresh certain time on specific interval)

Just create a view like,

```
import datetime
from django.http import JsonResponse


def get_certain_date(request):
   # or get certain date from database or somewhere else.
   return JsonResponse({'certain_date':datetime.datetime.now()})
```

And use ajax call to update html contents.

**Option 2** (Use when you dont want to update certain time untill user refreshes page)

render certain time in django view.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request): 
    render(request, "html.html", {'certain_time': certain_time})  #  get it from database.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it purely with frontend Javascript. No Django code needed at all. However, it depends on what you intend to do.

```
<p id="demo" ></p>
<script>
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;
if (today.getHours() >= 1){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Insert your message here!!";
}
else {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "We don't want you to know the message yet";

}
</script>
```

If the time when the user loads the page is past 1AM for the day (the time I am using given where I am for testing), it shows the "Insert your message here!!". If it is not yet that time, it shows "We don't want you to know the message yet".

Insert your chosen hour in the if statement and set your chosen message to the `innerHTML`.

Alternatively, you could use Javascript to show or hide an element. You can use something like this for that.

```
  if (if (today.getHours() >= 1)) {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
  }
```

For the case (proposed by Nishant) where you need it for the server time rather than the user time, you would get the hour from `datetime.datetime.now()`, and pass as a variable (say perhaps `curr_date_hour`) and substitute it into the Javascript if statement like so:

```
  if (if (today.getHours() >= {{curr_date_hour}})) {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
  }
```

Comment: using javascript only client side date time is visible. OP is asking about certain time and not current datetime.